# Convert SQL query to Eloquent Laravel based on two parameters

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a sql query:

```
SELECT lat, lng, SQRT(
        POW(69.1 * (lat - $lat), 2) +
        POW(69.1 * ($lng - lng) * COS(lat / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM locations HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance;
```

Now I want to convert it to Eloquent But here is the problem
TIll now, I have queried my tables based on one parameter
`Venue::where('lat',">",12.133)` But Now I wanna kinda run a procedure on my table And I don't know How to accomplish this kind of queries.
How Do yo do that?

Comment: Specifically, what kind of procedure do you want to run?

Comment: Not any procedure, just the select sql statement mentioned in question

Comment: I would suggest you look at the Query Builder documentation http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries it has a fluent interface so you can chain to your call so after your where you could do ->select and specify your values.

Comment: @Mark Davidson  I've used query builders before, this is not the first time for me to come with eloquent. but I haven't seen anywhere how to run that query with two parameters. that's my problem

Comment: Why dowvote the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really doubt you can get that query using Eloquent... But you can use query builder and `raw`:

```
Locations::select(DB::raw("
        lat,lng, SQRT(
            POW(69.1 * (lat - $lat), 2) +
            POW(69.1 * ($lng - lng) * COS(lat / 57.3), 2)) AS distance"))
->havingRaw('distance < 25')
->orderBy('distance')
```